# Find the probability that the dial will land somewhere between $15^\circ$ and $300^{\circ}$?

Tags: probability, distributions

> Suppose you spin a dial so that it comes to rest at a random position. Find the
> probability that the dial will land somewhere between $15^\circ$
> and $300^{\circ}$

I tried this problem but it is not sure. Can anyone verify?

$\underline{Attempt}$

$$P(\frac{\pi}{12}<x<\frac{5\pi}{3})=\int _{\pi/12}^{5\pi/3} \frac{1}{2\pi }{d\theta}=\frac{19}{24}$$

Is it correct? if not please correct me?

Comment: So 285/360=0.79 ? Maybe some more information about what this dial is and how it works would help.

Comment: @user2974951 you can post it as an answer. To the OP: $\pi/36$ is $5$ degrees.

Comment: As in the first comment I don't see why conversion to radians or integration is needed here. If the expected distribution is circular uniform (and you'd need grounds for any other hypothesis) the fraction you need is 285/360.

Comment: @user2974951 thank you I edited it

Comment: If you work in degrees rather than radians, then you have $\int_{15}^{300} \frac1{360}\,dx = \frac{285}{360}=\frac{19}{24}$

Comment: @Henry thank you very much

Comment: The question is ambiguous: the two angles determine two directions, which define two complementary sectors.  Which is the "between" sector??  Often, the convention is to take the *smaller* of the two, which in this case measures 75 degrees, which would make the answer 75/360 rather than 285/360.

Comment: @whuber Got it thank you vey much

Comment: @whuber is right, as usual. In my experience, the usual mathematical convention is to measure angles anti- or counterclockwise from the horizontal axis and the usual scientific or practical convention is to measures angles clockwise from the vertical axis (compass-wise would be an appropriate term).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your outcome is real (similarly for discrete) and bounded between 0 and 360$^\circ$ and each value in this interval is equally likely, then the probability of obtaining a number between 15 and 300$^\circ$ is

$$\frac{300-15}{360} \approx0.7916667$$

Comment: If the outcome is discrete, the answer is unlikely to be exactly 285/360, depending on whether 15 or 300 degrees are possible values.